# How to get all attributes of an object

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to get all attributes of an class (or object). Also all attributes that were not initialized.

The following code lists only the attribute "att2", but I want all (att1, att2, att3):

```js
class ObjA {
  att1: string;
  att2 = 'test';
  att3: number;
}

function getAttributes(obj: ObjA) {
  for (const item of Object.keys(obj)) {
    console.log('Attribute: ' + item);
  }
}

function mainTest() {
  const obj = new ObjA();
  getAttributes(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get them.

Code optimization in TS removes the undefined values from your object instances.

Simply instantiate them to falsy values (strings would be `''`, numbers would be `0`) so that your conditions are still respected, and your function should work.